# Efficiency with JavaScript Callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, socket.io

I just wanted to confirm a suspicion of mine.

I stumbled across an article which recommended using Socket.io in the following fashion:

```
var app = require('express').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(8080);

// Some unrelated stuff

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('action1', function (data) {
        // logic for action1
    });

    socket.on('action2', function (data) {
        // logic for action2
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // logic for disconnect
    });
});
```

I feel like the following would be a better use of resources:

```
var app = require('express').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(8080);

// Some unrelated stuff

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('action1', action1);
    socket.on('action2', action2);
    socket.on('disconnect', disconnect);
});

function action1(data) {
    // logic for action1
}

function action2(data) {
    // logic for action2
}

function disconnect() {
    // logic for disconnect
}
```

My feeling is that although the anonymous function that handles the `connection` event is only created in memory once, the anonymous functions that handle `action1`, `action2`, and `disconnect` are created in memory for every socket connection. The issue with the second approach is that `socket` is no longer in scope.

So firstly, is my suspicion about the creation of functions true? And secondly, if so is there a way to get `socket` in scope for the named functions?

Comment: I'm not familiar with V8 internals but it might be smart enough to compile the function once and re-use it everytime, just with a different scope attached.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: According to one of the techs on the V8 mailing list, yes, it "normally" is; see [my answer to KPthunder's other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10160351/157247).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a closure helps to keep the scope clean:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function () {
    function action1(data) {
        // logic for action1
    }
    function action2(data) {
        // logic for action2
    }
    function disconnect() {
        // logic for disconnect
    }
    return function (socket) {
        socket.on('action1', action1);
        socket.on('action2', action2);
        socket.on('disconnect', disconnect);
    }
}()); // <- note the immediate function call
```

To your questions:

> So firstly, is my suspicion about the creation of functions true?

Yes. The closure approach above prevents this, the callback functions are created only once. Plus: all see the correct parent scopes.

> And secondly, if so is there a way to get `socket` in scope for the named functions?

The `socket` will be available as `this` in the callbacks.

Comment: There's no difference in this example than using the anonymous closures - there's still a new "action1" created for each socket connection.  No more or less than in the original code sample.

Comment: @webnesto This is not true. What makes you think that?

Comment: socket.on('foo', function(){}); and function x(){}; socket.on('foo', x );  are functionally the same.  The only difference is that when the closure is named, there is the capacity for another reference to it.

Comment: Having your "function action1" definition inside the socket connection enclosure ensures that function action1 is defined for every socket connection (new method instantiated).  No different than the anonymous closure in the first example.  Why do *you* think it's any different?

Comment: OMG - I'm an idiot and didn't read closely enough.  You are 100% correct.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @webnesto For the future: I prefer a comment over a down-vote any time.

Comment: I honestly had tried to undo the downvote before I figured out what an imbecile I was being, but after too much time.  Again: my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, that the anonymous methods are created for each connection - and if you don't need scope, then the second method does avoid that.  If you need the socket scope there's no real way to avoid it.  If you want to keep the methods external (for some other reason) and still keep scope, you could always:

```
//...
socket.on('action1', function(){
  action1.apply( socket, arguments );
} );
//... and so forth.
```

But that has you back to creating a method signature for each connection, so I'm not sure what you'd be gaining.