# V8 Internals - Handling of Anonymous Functions

Tags: javascript, v8

For the full story, check out [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157063/efficiency-with-javascript-callbacks).

Basically, I had asked if it were more efficient to use named functions in the socket handlers for the following code:

```
var app = require('express').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(8080);

// Some unrelated stuff

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('action1', function (data) {
        // logic for action1
    });

    socket.on('action2', function (data) {
        // logic for action2
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // logic for disconnect
    });
});
```

The overall answer was yes (see the above link for more details), but the following comment was posted by [ThiefMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/thiefmaster):

> I'm not familiar with V8 internals but it might be smart enough to compile the function once and re-use it everytime, just with a different scope attached.

So now that's my question. Is V8 smart enough to compile anonymous functions once and reuse them with different scopes in situations where anonymous functions ordinarily lead to several function instances being created? For example, above I would expect the handler for the `connection` event to be created once but the handlers for `action1`, `action2`, and `disconnect` to be created for each connection. In the other question this was solved with named functions but I am more interested if this is necessary in V8 or if it will do some optimizations.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with the function being named or anonymous; it has to do with whether you create a new function on each connection. (See my answer for more on that.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. I [asked a very similar question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/BbvL5qFG_uc) (related in my case to creating functions from within a constructor function) on the V8 mailing list. I got the reply that the function's *code* is "...normally reused...", even though there's a separate function *object* each time (as required by the spec).

---

Note, though, that your question has nothing to do with whether the function is named or anonymous. The function in your example could have a name:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function handleConnection(socket) {
    socket.on('action1', function (data) {
        // logic for action1
    });

    socket.on('action2', function (data) {
        // logic for action2
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // logic for disconnect
    });
});
```

That uses a *named function expression*, which is perfectly valid and handled correctly by V8. (Sadly, it's [not handled correctly by IE8 and earlier](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html), which create two completely different functions at totally different times. But as you're using V8, you don't have to worry about that.)

Comment: Why does it not matter whether the function is named or anonymous? It's quite possible that it doesn't matter, but do we know for sure if V8 handles this situation consistently for both kinds of functions? Though out of scope of the original question, is also possible that V8 has a consistent implementation, but other JavaScript runtimes do not?

Comment: @anishpatel - Re your first question, for me, it fails the laugh test to suspect that whether the function has a name or not affects this optimization. Re your second, this question is specifically about V8, but Kevin Millikin, the V8 contributor who answered me on the mailing list, said *"...I don't really know for sure what any other JS engine does, but I would be quite surprised if they duplicated code for distinct function objects created from the same site in the source text."* That was in 2011, when other engines were a lot less optimized than they are now. :-)