# Jshint: Anonmyous function within a loop (Issue)

Tags: javascript, jshint

My problem is similar to [JSHint won't let me use 'forEach' in a 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451865/jshint-wont-let-me-use-foreach-in-a-for-loop)

We have about 2k JS lines in currently project, recently included `jshint` checking, one common issue is the below sample code would throw

> Don't make functions within a loop.

sample code:

```
var s1 = '12345'.split('');
var oo = { a: s1, b: s1, c: s1};

function odd(obj){
    var tmp = [];
    for (var key in obj){
        obj[key].forEach( function(val){
            if(val%2>0) tmp.push(val);
        });
    }
    return tmp;
}


odd(oo);
```

my fix was:

```
function odd(obj){
    var tmp = [], tmpFn;
    tmpFn = function(val){
        if(val%2>0) tmp.push(val);
    };
    for (var key in obj){
        obj[key].forEach(tmpFn);
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

I have checked, this works, but I am unsure if this is the right way to fix old code, would there be any unwanted side effects from this fix? or should I just ignore the warning, as the old code looks much cleaner?

***EDIT*** : I missed a for loop, updated sample code with it.

Comment: I'm not seeing this error when copy/pasting your code. Can you show a more complete code sample that displays the issue?

Comment: That code *isn't* creating functions in a loop, not unless you have `function odd() { ... }` in a loop, which is a much more serious syntax error: Function *declarations* aren't allowed to be inside control structures, they must be at the top level of an execution context (e.g., outside of all control structures in the function or global context).

Comment: Side note: I'd use `filter` for that.

Comment: Finally: Function declarations don't need a `;` after them. `;` is for terminating statements (other than the block statement); declarations aren't statements.

Comment: you should avoid creating unnecessary variables,functions in loops as they consume a lot of resources and hence marked as bad practices. Here in your code you want to filter a list of records which follows a condition....you should prepare the predicate function first and then pass it to the loop.

Comment: @Vijay , if I am correct, that is what my fix is doing...

Comment: @SecondRikudo , ```function(el) { return el % 2 > 0 }``` would still show warning,  also, ```forEach``` or ```filter``` makes no difference as it is just a sample code, my main issue here is tacking jshint warning

Comment: Yes, you were asking if this was right way to fix the code...and I presented why it was right :)

Comment: @mido22 please make a code sample, and paste it to http://jshint.com/, and make sure that the warning you're speaking of shows. Right now, we cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @SecondRikudo, my bad, code updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ignore that warning, it's really unnecessary to create a new function for each run of your loop.

This approach is better, and as long as you stay within the odd() function with the definition, it won't have any side effects, it will see the same variable states as it would as an anonymous function passed to forEach.

Edit: even if you do decide to ignore that warning, do it consistently - either use a jshint configuration which doesn't consider this a mistake, or add a jshint comment to temporarily disable this warning type inside the code (use jshint --verbose to get the warning code for selective toggling), don't let any displayed jshint warning go without notice, that defeats the purpose of having code analysis in the first place.

Comment: I think this warning is not to avoid.....until you are creating dynamic templates which are passed as anonymous functions on runtime...you should avoid such code.